# Error: Add row dynamically in a table with textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok, I want to add row in table with one checkbox and 3 or 4 textbox. But my script is not working that way , I am just getting one checkbox. I am new BTW. Here is my script, please help. I am posting only the script here

```
<script language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell3.appendChild(element2);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        element3.type = "text";
        element3.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell3.appendChild(element3);


    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when executing `addRow()`? To check this use chrome -> press F12 -> click on console. You could also use something like FireBug.

Comment: opps, there is a simple error :| i wrote cell3 twice . Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, always use the console, it saved my ass numerous of times.

Comment: haha, ok, cool tip. ;)

Comment: JasonK is it possible to do auto-complete text from database..in these text-boxes which created through javascript ?

Comment: Yes it sure is, but that's a whole different question. I use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for this. You can call it like `$('input[name="txtbox"]').autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });` The source is a JavaScript array like `var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "PHP",
      "Ruby",
    ];`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element2);
```

is worng its should be  ,( simple mistake )

```
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
```

Comment: What is this? Could you please explain a little bit more

Comment: i used cell3 twice in the above question thats why its not working.